# Init Vue Awesome swiper on product card hover

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, swiper.js

ideally I need vue awesome swiper to init on product card hover, so until the user hovers, catalog loads only one img per product instead of multiple.

HTML

```html
    <div
      @mouseover="handleMouseOver"
      @mouseleave="handleMouseLeave"
    />
      <div
        v-if="media.length > 1"
        ref="swiper"
        v-swiper:mySwiper="swiperOption"
      >
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div
            v-for="image in images"
            :key="image.id"
            class="swiper-slide image__wrapper"
          >
            <img
              :src="image.attributes.src"
              :width="imgWidth"
              :height="imgHeight"
              :alt="imgAlt"
            >
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Component

```js
  data: () => ({
    swiperOption: {
      loop: true,
      slidesPerView: 1,
      centeredSlides: true,
      spaceBetween: 30,
    },
  }),

  methods: {
    slideStart() {
      if (this.$refs.swiper) {
        this.mySwiper.activeIndex = 2;
        this.mySwiper.autoplay.start();
      }
    },
    slideStop() {
      if (this.$refs.swiper) {
        this.mySwiper.autoplay.stop();
        this.mySwiper.activeIndex = 1;
      }
    },
    handleMouseOver() {
      this.isHovered = true;
      this.slideStart();
    },
    handleMouseLeave() {
      this.isHovered = false;
      this.slideStop();
    },
 },
```

What I've tried and what problems encountered:
At first, I've added isHovered condition to v-if and used  element in v-else, however after hover swiper refuses to autoplay (but reacts on activeIndex change)

After that I've tried adding init:false to swiperOption and this.$mySwiper.init() on hover, but it crashes whenever I'm trying to leave the page: [image: error]

Would appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by creating a parent div, and moving 'v-if' logic with hover condition there.